# WPF Tutorials/Resources for Visual Studio Express

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-express

I'm creating a UI with WPF, but I don't want to spend the $500 on Expression Studio. 
Where do I find resources that walk me through creating a WPF application within Visual Studio.  I'm looking to use some basic animations and want to use transparency on a couple of objects.
I've tried looking for resources other places, and all I've been able to find is links to books published 6 years ago, so I was hoping to find something a little more recent.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1):

You can start here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf1.aspx